# How to update compiler and rebuild Alamofire

Tags: xcode, swift, carthage

Today I noticed this error on my Xcode project...

`Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'Alamofire' and try again:/Users/Shane/Documents/MyProject/MyProect/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule`

Has anyone else seen this before and/or know how to fix it?

I've already cleaned my project and deleted my Derived Data. Also my Xcode version 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by reinstalling Carthage and then going to my project via the terminal and doing `carthage update`. 
After that was done I went back to Xcode and to be safe did a clean, a build folder clean, deleted the derived data folder again, and then built the project.

Answer (score 1):

For me Cleaning up the Build folder <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> worked.